# Deleting all Options on theme switch

Tags: theme-development, switch-theme

I am looking to reset or delete all options on theme switch. Currently when I switch themes my options in my current custom theme that I am developing, will transfer to its associated child themes. This should not happen.

**How do i delete all options upon theme switch?**

Comment: Can you select these options? Can you show, how will you select them? Then I'll do the rest ;)

Comment: Do you mean all site options (ie, stuff set with `update_option()`) or just the theme's options?  If the latter, use [`remove_theme_mods()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_theme_mods).